# Canvas is stretching using drawImage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas

I am aware of having to set the size of a `<canvas>` element using the `width` and `height` attribute to avoid stretching. I have no CSS applied to it other than background-color.

I am using `ctx.drawImage()` to show a video. **The weird thing is, my `640x480` video plays fine and is not stretched. It is only happening on my `640x360` videos for now.**

I have created an angular directive that draws video onto a canvas element and it all works except for the stretching. Here is my code that draws the video element onto the canvas:

```
scope.renderPlayer = function()
{
  var $this = this;
  attributes.width = player.videoWidth;
  attributes.height = player.videoHeight;
  canvas.setAttribute('width', attributes.width);
  canvas.setAttribute('height', attributes.height);

  (function loop()
  {
    if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended)
    {
      ctx.drawImage($this, 0,0, attributes.width, attributes.height);
      setTimeout(loop, 1000/30);
    }
  })();
};
player.addEventListener('play', scope.renderPlayer);
```

I assure you the source of the videos don't have that stretching artifacting on the bottom as shown in the image below (You can really see the pixels stretched on the bottom right). My initial width and height of the canvas element is 640x480 and it will change depending on the size of the loaded video.

[image: stretching at the bottom]

Comment: turns out to be a bug in chrome on PC: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=515941&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified with thanks to @Madness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this CSS fixes it for you, I need it whenever I use canvas:

```
canvas {
    display: block;
}
```

the `canvas` tag is susceptible to the same pitfalls as the `img` tag in that it renders extra space below it. You are correct to set the dimensions as HTML attributes though, what a pain.

Comment: darn, I was hoping it would be easy as that, but no luck

Comment: My canvas element is clearly 640x360 too, I don't get it

Comment: I just tried it in firefox and IE and it works fine. I forgot to mention this is happening in chrome

Comment: I don't have it live anywhere, plus I am working with laravel which I am new to so I am not sure how to deploy my project quite yet

Comment: Give this a read through a make sure you have followed his recommendations http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/ This is from one of the Chrome Developers. He touches on some pitfalls. What I have noticed with the Canvas is that you often chase a problem that is really derived from something much earlier, not what you are thinking. So it is all about coming out of the gate correctly.

Comment: yeah, I haven't heard of a 0.5 offset. I will read that page and see if I have any luck

Comment: I have looked everywhere for anything on this issue, and haven't found anything. Have you had any luck?

Comment: I just got back in the office so I will be searching today on how to fix it

Comment: I started a chat if you would like to discuss it more. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84824/room-for-madness-and-ronnie

Comment: FYI, version 45 of chrome has fixed this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with `canvas` in a while, but you can give `ctx.drawImage($this)` a try, also you can `requestAnimationFrame` and use it instead of `setTimeout`:

```
scope.renderPlayer = function()
{
  var $this = this;
  canvas.width = player.width;    // if canvas is a Jquery Object, try canvas[0].width
  canvas.height = player.height;    // if canvas is a Jquery Object, try canvas[0].height

  (function loop()
  {
    if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended)
    {
      ctx.drawImage($this);      
      setTimeout(loop, 1000/30);
    }
  })();
};
player.addEventListener('play', scope.renderPlayer);
```

Comment: while, `requestAnimationFrame()` didn't solve the issue, it sounds like it is more efficient than `setTimeout`, thank you