# Memory leak in canvas with getImageData and or putImageData

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, memory-leaks

I am creating a realtime video editor that allows you to add certain video effects using the canvas. You'll notice in my code, I actually have two canvas elements. The process is:

1. `<video>` begins to play invisibly using CSS.
2. The visible `<canvas>` renders the video onto the canvas.
3. In order to add the realtime effects, I need to have another hidden `<canvas>` that will process the video image and then return that processed frame to the visible `<canvas>`. This is where I use `getImageData()` and `putImageData()`

I am seeing a memory leak in chrome right now. I have found many threads talking about this, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I removed the "video effects" code for testing purposes and for the fiddle. It still memory leaks without the effect processing.

FIDDLE: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/o8z4ocLd/</kbd>

Watch the `Memory` using Chromes Task Manager (Burger Menu -> More Tools -> Task Manager)

You will notice the memory climb and then fall back down, only to rise higher than the last time. I have watched it climb well into 1+GB of memory usage to eventually crash the tab. I have tried different variations of `setTimeout` and `requestAnimationFrame`. All seem to result in a memory leak.

**edit**

one thing worth mentioning is this seems to be happening in only chrome. Firefox seems to handle the garbage collecting better. I haven't seen firefox go above 500mb.

Comment: Instead of combining requestAnimationFrame plus setTimeout, refactor to use the built-in timestamp version of rAF to control elapsed time. rAF lessens the stacking of uncompletable frames.  If you're still getting stacked frame memory loss then you will have to reduce the FPS -- at least on Chrome.

Comment: @markE built in timestamp version? I haven't been able to find something like that, can you elaborate?

Comment: Here's an annotated example of how to use rAF's timestamp to calculate and use elapsed time: https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3k2vypu3/ :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my chrome self updated to version 45 this morning. 45 came out sept. 1st 2015 and this issue appears to be fixed! I am no longer receiving a memory leak. This update has also fixed another issue I was having in this thread:

[Canvas is stretching using drawImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735578/canvas-is-stretching-using-drawimage)